# Displaytag footer average

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag

Im using displaytag to create reports. In the footer of the report  i would like to show the average sum of a couple of my columns. Average sum of "pris" and "dekningsprosent".

Is this possible with displaytag? I have seen there is a method for counting totals, but i cant find for average.

Hope you guys can help! Here is my code so far:

```
<display:table name="rapportList" class="table" requestURI="" id="rapportList" export="true" pagesize="25">

<display:column property="leilighetId" sortable="true" titleKey="report.header.leilighetId"/>
<display:column property="pris" sortable="true" titleKey="report.header.price" format="{0,number,currency}"/>
<display:column property="dekningProsent" sortable="true" titleKey="report.header.coverage" format="{0,number,percent}"/>

<display:footer>
  //What goes in here to get the average?
</display:footer>
</display>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already try this feature? http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-columnsummation.jsp

Comment: If you avoided display tag and used the struts iterator tag it would make the issue more explicit (there is less magic, and an EL/OGNL solution could be provided). You could crunch the average in the action. You could also solve the issue with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

in your `displayTag` declarations, you put the `varTotals` properties:

```
<display:table name="rapportList" class="table" requestURI="" id="rapportList" export="true" pagesize="25"  varTotals="myTotalValue">
```

and after that you must in each column you want to sum the property `total="true"` :

```
<display:column property="pris" sortable="true" titleKey="report.header.price" format="{0,number,currency}"/>
```

the last step is make your footer receive the sum calculations, like:

```
    <display:footer>
   <td>${myTotalValue.column2}</td>
</display:footer>
```

Don't forget that the number of the columns in this case starts with one, and not zero like the arrays patterns